# How to pass class public member function as a the template parameter?

Tags: c++, class, templates, hashmap, parameter-passing

I'm working with google sparse hashmap library. And I have the following class template:

```
template <class Key, class T,
          class HashFcn = std::tr1::hash<Key>,   
          class EqualKey = std::equal_to<Key>,
          class Alloc = libc_allocator_with_realloc<std::pair<const Key, T> > >
class dense_hash_map {
.....
typedef dense_hashtable<std::pair<const Key, T>, Key, HashFcn, SelectKey,
                        SetKey, EqualKey, Alloc> ht;
.....

};
```

Now I have defined my own class as:

```
class my_hashmap_key_class {

private:
    unsigned char *pData;
    int data_length;

public:
    // Constructors,Destructor,Getters & Setters

    //equal comparison operator for this class
    bool operator()(const hashmap_key_class &rObj1, const hashmap_key_class &rObj2) const;

    //hashing operator for this class
    size_t operator()(const hashmap_key_class &rObj) const;

};
```

Now I want to pass `my_hashmap_key_class` as a `Key`, `my_hashmap_key_class::operator()(const hashmap_key_class &rObj1, const hashmap_key_class &rObj2)` as `EqualKey` and `my_hashmap_key_class::operator()(const hashmap_key_class &rObj)` as `HashFcn` to `dense_hash_map` class as parameters while using it in main function as:

main.cpp:

```
dense_hash_map<hashmap_key_class, int, ???????,???????> hmap;
```

What is the proper way of passing the class member functions as template parameters??

I tried passing like:

```
dense_hash_map<hashmap_key_class, int, hashmap_key_class::operator(const hashmap_key_class &rObj1, const hashmap_key_class &rObj2),hashmap_key_class::operator()(const hashmap_key_class &rObj)> hmap;
```

But I get compilation error as operator is not detected. Please help me realize where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I guess that you want those operators to be `static`. Also, why don't you use `operator==` for equality comparison? (You still have to define it manually)

Comment: Make the operator `static`.

Comment: Or use the rather odd, but not unheard of, fact that your class is its own equality functor, and simply pass `my_hashmap_key_class`. Note that an instance will be constructed to perform the comparison, and neither of the parameters will be the constructed comparator itself. The same is true for the `HashFn` parameter. I don't see it very often, but it should none-the-less work as you have defined this code. And note, your class must support default-construction (I assume it does).

Comment: I.e. `dense_hash_map<my_hashmap_key_class, int, my_hashmap_key_class,my_hashmap_key_class> hmap` should work.

Comment: dense_hash_map<my_hashmap_key_class, int, my_hashmap_key_class,my_hashmap_key_class> hmap works......... but gives compiler warning as -----warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
warning: RTTI symbol not found for ....continued

Comment: ...continued -----class 'google::dense_hashtable<std::pair<my_hashmap_key_class const, int>, my_hashmap_key_class, my_hashmap_key_class, google::dense_hash_map<my_hashmap_key_class, int, my_hashmap_key_class, my_hashmap_key_class, google::libc_allocator_with_realloc<std::pair<my_hashmap_key_class const, int> > >::SelectKey, google::dense_hash_map<my_hashmap_key_class, int, my_hashmap_key_class, my_hashmap_key_class, google::libc_allocator_with_realloc<std::pair<my_hashmap_key_class const, int> > >::SetKey, my_hashmap_key_class, ......continued

Comment: ...continued----- google::libc_allocator_with_realloc<std::pair<my_hashmap_key_class const, int> > >::Settings'

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, you should write the equality as an `operator==`. Also, either make these operators static or remove one of their parameters (the "this" pointer will be the left hand operand for the equality test), otherwise they won't work as expected.

```
//equal comparison operator for this class
bool operator==(const hashmap_key_class &rObj2) const;

//hashing operator for this class
size_t operator()() const;
```

Then, your class is ready for client code like this:

```
my_hashmap_key_class a = ...;
my_hashmap_key_class b = ...;

a == b;   // calls a.operator==(b), i.e. compares a and b for equality
a();      // calls a.operator()(), i.e. computes the hash of a
```

Then, you should be fine by using the default template parameters.

Comment: that's true.....but I'm not interested in the way the object is instantiated or member functions are defined (because the google sparse hash code needs our class to be in specific format). But rather how to use the member functions as template parameters and make use of them.

Comment: "Then, you should be fine by using the default template parameters" is the part I need to know & how to achieve it

Comment: Simply omit the parameters: `dense_hash_map<my_hashmap_key_class, int>` *should* do it, but I can't test it. Please report if there is a problem with this.

Comment: it gives compilation error as :  undefined reference to `std::tr1::hash<my_hashmap_key_class>::operator()(my_hashmap_key_class) const'

Comment: In this case try `dense_hash_map<my_hashmap_key_class, int, my_hashmap_key_class>`

Comment: it gives the same compilation warning as I mentioned in the above comments----- warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000 warning: RTTI symbol not found for .....